# Extending session / cookie lifetime for customers (Amazon-style)

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, session, cookie

When visiting Amazon, I've noticed that I always get greeted by name:

[image]

However, when I try click onto my account, it forces me to log-in again. I'm not 100% sure about the logic here, but I'm assuming they're identifying me by cookie.

This is really useful because it allows you to target specific products to specific customers based on their order history, like this:

[image]

How is it possible to identify customers who aren't logged in by cookie? Is it possible to set up a similar behaviour to Amazon?

Do I just need to extend the cookie lifetime? I'm not very familiar with this aspect of Magento.

Comment: I think `Persistent Shopping Cart` is the closest Magento get's to the feature, but I don't believe that deals with customer name.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Cags states Persistent Cart is probably the closest thing to what your describing so the short answer would be no its not possible out of the box.

However, you could look into extending the functionality a little. Create a module which observes the event **customer_login**

As you might expect this would be used when a customer logs in, from this you could then create some abstract cookie to set their name.

The same module would also need to check for the **customer_logout** since this action would be triggered when someone actually logs out you can use it to destroy your created cookie which would have its own lifetime separately from the Magento sessions.

This would then allow you in your template files (or perhaps via a suitable helper) to retrieve the contents of your cookie and display their name similar to how Amazon keeps you logged in by its name cookie.

I do not recommend you put anything into the cookie which could be potentially used to identify the customer ID itself however.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the cookie session for guests in admin system>config>web>cookie lifetime.  But your setting also needs mirrored in your php.ini file session.gc_lifetime, should match or exceed your admin setting.

You can also set your admin session separately via system>config>admin

And yes, persistence is best option for logged in customers.